# c# linq combine 2 dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `Dictionary<string, Item>`s.  `Item` has a has a public property `int Level`.

I want to combine these two dictionaries where keys are unique and I want to be able to specify level on both.

Something like

```
dictionary 1 = all items that level < 10
dictionary 2 = all items level < 20

combine dictionary 2 with 1 (where Value.Level < 10)
if the Key is unique and the Value.Level < 20
```

I can easily do this with foreach loops. I can also do this with multiple linq queries.
However i can't seem to figure out how to make this one single linq query.

Edit- Per your request John here is the code with foreach

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Item>> itemDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Item>>();

Dictionary<string, Item> items = new Dictionary<string,Item>();

            if (itemDictionary.ContainsKey(comboBox.Text))
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Item> kvp in itemDictionary[comboBox.Text])
                {
                    if (!items.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) && kvp.Value.Level <= int.Parse(textBox.Text))
                        items.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }
            }

            if (itemDictionary.ContainsKey(comboBox1.Text))
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Spell> kvp in itemDictionary[comboBox1.Text])
                {
                    if (!items.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) && kvp.Value.Level <= int.Parse(textBox1.Text))
                        items.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }
            }
            var query = from s in items
                        orderby s.Value.Level
                        select s;

            foreach (var i in query)
               listBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", i.Value.Level, i.Key));
```

Comment: So your desired result is a dictionary with all the items in dictionary 1 plus all the items in dictionary 2 who's key does not exist in dictionary 1?

Comment: When you say "combine" do you mean into a new dictionary, or by inserting the elements from dictionary 2 into dictionary 1?

Comment: @scmccart, it sounds more like a *subset* of 1 and a *subset* of 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine these two dictionaries where keys are unique"? What do you want to happen if the same key is in both dictionaries? If you could show us your current code using foreach, we could probably help you...

Comment: Anthony is correct i'm looking for a subset of both dictionarys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that code makes it clear what you want to accomplish. So the end result should be a dictionary comprised of the items from both dictionaries that meet the specified level. If an item exists in both dictionaries than the item from the first dictionary will be preferred. While it is possible to accomplish this in a single Linq query you would end up repeating some work. Here is what I came up with, it runs in LinqPad if you want to try it out easily.

```
var itemsOne = new[] {
    new { Name = "A", Level = 1 },
    new { Name = "B", Level = 2 },
    new { Name = "C", Level = 3 },
    new { Name = "D", Level = 4 }
}.ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => i);

var itemsTwo = new[] {
    new { Name = "C", Level = 10 },
    new { Name = "D", Level = 20 },
    new { Name = "E", Level = 30 },
    new { Name = "F", Level = 40 }
}.ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => i);

var itemsOneLevel = 3;
var itemsTwoLevel = 30;

var validFromItemsOne = (from item in itemsOne
                         where item.Value.Level <= itemsOneLevel
                         select item).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);

var validFromItemsTwo = from item in itemsTwo
                        where item.Value.Level <= itemsTwoLevel
                            && !validFromItemsOne.ContainsKey(item.Key)
                        select item;

var items = validFromItemsOne
    .Concat(validFromItemsTwo)
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can easily do what you want in foreach loops, then you've already written the code. That tells me that the foreach code would probably be more readable and easier to maintain than a complicated LINQ query.

This sounds like the perfect case for leaving foreach loop code in place. LINQ may be newer but that doesn't always mean it is better.

Comment: +1 I hate debugging `LINQ`. It has it's moments, but a foreach is a lot better in some cases

Comment: If i understood linq better then readability becomes a debatable point.  My intent is to get a better grasp with linq not so much producing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood you correct: you want to have records that exist in both dictionaries. Anyway my example can be tailored to your particular needs.

```
Dictionary<string, string> d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>(), d2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var merged = d1
            .Join(d2, d1key => d1key.Key, d2key => d2key.Key,
                (i1, i2) => new { Key = i1.Key, Value1 = i1.Value, Value2 = i2.Value })
            .ToDictionary(t => t.Key);
```

Merged will contain only items that existed in both dictionaries, and will be able to get data for each of the items like merged["key"].Value1 and merged["key"].Value2
For example I`ve used anonymous type (new {}). So you will be able to access Value1 and Value2 only in the same method, or in binding because they are dynamic anyway.
In other cases you should create a type to store combined result.

Comment: d1 and d2 combine them so that d3 = items that are unique.  if d1 and d2 both have a value where level meets the condition then only d1 value is added and d2 value is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension that I think will work for this scenario.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Combine<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> firstSet,
        IDictionary<TKey, TValue> secondSet,
        Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, bool> firstFilter,
        Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, bool> secondFilter)
    {
        return firstSet
        .Where(firstFilter)
        .Concat(secondSet.Where(secondFilter))
        .GroupBy(d => d.Key)
        .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.First().Value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var itemsOne = new[] {
    new { Name = "A", Level = 1 },
    new { Name = "B", Level = 2 },
    new { Name = "C", Level = 3 },
    new { Name = "D", Level = 4 }
}.ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => i);

var itemsTwo = new[] {
    new { Name = "C", Level = 10 },
    new { Name = "D", Level = 20 },
    new { Name = "E", Level = 30 },
    new { Name = "F", Level = 40 }
}.ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => i);

itemsOne
.Combine(itemsTwo,
    kvp => kvp.Value.Level <= 3,
    kvp => kvp.Value.Level <= 30)
    .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d=> d.Value.Level)
```

Result:

```
A 1 
B 2 
C 3 
D 20 
E 30
```